# Add colored bar in the left side instead of the top of shinydashboard() box

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, box

Can I create a `box()` within shinydashboard which has the red bar in the left side instead of top? Like here:[image]

I took ideas from : [here](https://dgranjon.shinyapps.io/shinydashboardPlusDemo/).

Maybe I can add it with an alternative way if there is no `shinydashboard()` built in solution.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
box(
            title = "title, 
            closable = TRUE, 
            width = 10,
            status = "danger", 
            solidHeader = F, 
            collapsible = TRUE,
            collapsed = T
            )
)
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it with css

.box.box-danger {
border-top-color: white;
border-left-color: red;
border-left-style: solid;
}

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$style(
      type = 'text/css',
      ".box-danger{border-top-style: none; border-left-color: red; border-left-style: solid;}"
    ),
  box(
      title = "title", 
            closable = TRUE, 
            width = 10,
            status = "danger", 
            solidHeader = F, 
            collapsible = TRUE,
            collapsed = T
            )
)
)


server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Sample]